# How to create a folder inside proc/pid

Tags: c, linux-kernel, filesystems, kernel-module

I am writing a character device with a Linux Kernel Module and the kernel version is : 4.14.
Basically, a user space process with a given tgid can interact with my device through ioctl.

I need to make a new directory inside /proc/pid (where pid is the tgid of the processes that have interacted with my device) so that I can create inside this new directory some files with some logs.

Is it possible to create a new directory inside /proc/pid without re-compiling the linux kernel?

In particular, I have tried to use :

```
struct proc_dir_entry *proc_create(
const char *name, umode_t mode,
struct proc_dir_entry *parent,
const struct file_operations *proc_fops)
```

but I am not able to get the `struct proc_dir_entry *` of the pid folder I want to write in because I am not able to include `fs/proc/internal.h` where PDE is defined.

This is what I have tried to do :

```
struct file *fp = filp_open("/proc/1",....);
struct proc_dir_entry *parent ;
parent = PDE(fp->f_dentry->d_inode);
```

Any solution ?

Comment: My understanding is that /proc/pid is entirely virtual. It doesn't actually exist physically, and is only accessible while the pid is live?

Comment: You'd probably still need to write a kernel module, but you don't have to recompile the kernel, no. Creating a "file" in /proc: https://linux.die.net/lkmpg/x769.html

Comment: @Cinder Biscuits I know how to write in /proc but not how to write in /proc/pid

Comment: @Gem Taylor yes it is true, this why I think the solution is to dynamically add an entry to tgid_base_stuff in fs/proc/base.c, but I don t know how

Comment: You'd have to modify the kernel. The only way I can think to do it is to create your own /proc/pidplus tree or whatever.

Comment: Adding stuff under /proc/pid is not a good idea...  E.g. how are you going to handle unexpected termination of process - when /proc/pid gets removed?

If you really need per-pid objects on procfs then better to create those under your own hierarchy, i.e. /proc/yourmodule/pid